Solve a system of quadratic equations, where all numbers in vectors and matrices are complex numbers.
How to solve $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{C}^{M}$ from the following systems, where all variables are complex number. $y_m \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbf{A}_m$ are known.  $\mathbf{A}_m\in\mathbb{C}^{M\times M}$ is symmetric matrix, and its elements are also complex numbers.
\begin{align}
    y_1&=\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}_1\mathbf{x}\\
    y_2&=\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}_2\mathbf{x}\\
    &\dots\\
    y_M&=\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}_M\mathbf{x}  
\end{align}
Actually, this is a problem encountered in signal processing. $\mathbf{x}$ is the complex signal to be estimated.

The optimization problem can be written as:
$$ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \sum_{i = 1}^{M} {\left\| \boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{A}_{i} \boldsymbol{x} - {y}_{i} \right\|}_{2}^{2} $$
Using Kronecker Product identity for Matrix Equations one can formulate:
$$ \boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{A}_{i} \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{a}_{i}^{T} \hat{\boldsymbol{x}} $$
Where $\boldsymbol{a}_{i} = \operatorname{Vec} \left( \boldsymbol{A}_{i} \right)$ and $\hat{\boldsymbol{x}} = \boldsymbol{x} \otimes \boldsymbol{x}$ with $\operatorname{Vec} \left( \cdot \right)$ being the Vectorization operator and $\otimes$ being the Kronecker Product operator.
Given that the whole problem can be rewritten as:
$$ \arg \min_{\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| \hat{\boldsymbol{A}} \hat{\boldsymbol{x}} - \boldsymbol{y} \right\|}_{2}^{2} $$
Where:
$$ \boldsymbol{y} = \begin{bmatrix} {y}_{1} \\ {y}_{2} \\ \vdots \\ {y}_{M} \end{bmatrix}, \; \hat{\boldsymbol{A}} = \begin{bmatrix} - \boldsymbol{a}_{i}^{T} - \\ - \boldsymbol{a}_{2}^{2} - \\ - \vdots - \\ - \boldsymbol{a}_{M} - \end{bmatrix}$$
Which is a regular LS problem to solve.
Yet, then to solve the Kronecker Product will be a challenge as in Method to Reverse a Kronecker Product.
Otherwise, you may just use iterative methods using the original formulation.
Remarks

The $\arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \sum_{i = 1}^{M} {\left\| \boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{A}_{i} \boldsymbol{x} - {y}_{i} \right\|}_{2}^{2}$ formulation is not a convex problem. Easy to see as if $\boldsymbol{x}$ is an optimal solution, then $-\boldsymbol{x}$ is as well yet $\boldsymbol{0}$ is not which is on the line between them.
Solving the other approach requires rebuilding the matrix $\boldsymbol{R} = \operatorname{Reshape} \left( \hat{\boldsymbol{x}}, M, M \right)$ which does the inverse of the Vectorization operator (Tensor Reshaping). If $\boldsymbol{R}$ is a rank 1 symmetric matrix, then $\boldsymbol{x} = \sqrt{{\sigma}_{1}} \boldsymbol{u}_{1}$ where ${\sigma}_{1}$ is the 1st singular value and $\boldsymbol{u}_{1}$ is the first columns of $\boldsymbol{U}$ of the Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) of $\boldsymbol{R}$.
The problem is tricky. I'd start solving it robustly for real numbers then move to complex. Also make sure you get the properties of $\boldsymbol{A}$ correctly. Is it Complex and Symmetric or Complex and Hermitian? Is it PSD?




Thank you very much for your answer. In the new optimization problem，$\hat{x}$ has  $M^2$ unknown variables, while $\hat{A}$ has only $M$ rows, which means that  $\hat{x}$ may not have a unique solution. So how to  solve this problem?

@user1452777, See the link of solving the Kronecker Product. If you share the data as CSV / mat or npz file I can try solving it with code.

Thank you for your detailed explanation. $\mathbf{A}_m$ is Complex and Symmetric and rank 1, i.e.,  $\mathbf{A}_m=\mathbf{a}_m\mathbf{a}_m^T$, where $\mathbf{a}_m\in\mathbb{C}^{M\times 1}=[e^{j\theta_1},\dots,e^{j\theta_M}]^T$. In addition, the original system is a system of quadratic nonlinear equations, under what conditions does its solution have uniqueness?

@user1452777, Are you sure it is only Transpose with Conjugation? It looks like originated form array processing. Mathematically, there won't be uniqueness as you won't be able to say the difference between $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $-\boldsymbol{x}$ for reals and similarly with proper conjugation on the complex field.

It's only Transpose, but not Conjugate Transpose. For channels, the TX to RX channel is the transpose of the RX to TX channel, not the conjugate transpose.  If the solution only has a difference in sign, this seems acceptable for estimation.
